# Grid Column Filtering Issue in Extjs

Tags: extjs

I've created a grid panel and I want to apply some filtering to several columns. But I'm faced with a problem about filtering. Is it possible to set default filtering while datecolumn object (xtype:'datecolumn') is creating ? How can I apply default filtering option when the gridpanel is loaded ?
Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: What kind of filter do you use? If you use a range filter and need two different values, this is really tricky. Otherwise, you can set [`itemDefaults.value`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.grid.filters.filter.Base.html#cfg-itemDefaults) to the value you wish to filter for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [gridfilters plugin](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.grid.filters.Filters.html) for this.

Following is a modified version of the example available in documentation of [Date filter](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.grid.filters.filter.Date.html)

```js
var shows = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    fields: ['id','show', {
          name: 'airDate',
          type: 'date',
          dateFormat: 'Y-m-d'
    }],
    data: [
        {id: 0, show: 'Battlestar Galactica', airDate: '1978-09-17'},
        {id: 1, show: 'Doctor Who', airDate: '1963-11-23'},
        {id: 2, show: 'Farscape', airDate: '1999-03-19'},
        {id: 3, show: 'Firefly', airDate: '2002-12-20'},
        {id: 4, show: 'Star Trek', airDate: '1966-09-08'},
        {id: 5, show: 'Star Wars: Christmas Special', airDate: '1978-11-17'}
    ]
});

Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    title: 'Sci-Fi Television',
    height: 250,
    width: 375,
    store: shows,
    plugins: 'gridfilters',
    columns: [{
        dataIndex: 'id',
        text: 'ID',
        width: 50
    },{
        dataIndex: 'show',
        text: 'Show',
        flex: 1
    },{
        xtype: 'datecolumn',
        dataIndex: 'airDate',
        text: 'Original Air Date',
        width: 125,
        filter: {
            type: 'date',
            operator: 'on',
            value: {eq:new Date('1999-03-19')}   // equals or ON
            //value: {lt:new Date('1999-03-19')} // less then or BEFORE
            //value: {gt:new Date('1999-03-19')} // greater then or AFTER
            
        }
    }]
});
```